# React Native/Redux State of a Generated List from Parent Component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, state

I have a React-Native Component that I am using that has a list generated in it that contains a state within each item list. The state which I am looking to get from each item is whether it is "checked" or not.

In the parent component I have the button and then the list that is generated and then build with a child component for the list items. How would I make it so that when the button is clicked, that it could log out whether or not the state for each item is "checked."

My purpose down the road is to create a list of items that will save whether or not the item is checked or not.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, 
  Platform, 
  Image, 
  Text, 
  Button, 
  ScrollView, 
  ListView,
  AsyncStorage
} from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


import Expo from 'expo';
import SettingsTeams from '../components/SettingsTeams';

import { STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT, SCREEN_WIDTH } from '../constants';




class Settings extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
    });

    this.dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(this.props.leagueteams.MLS);
  }

  renderRow(leagueteams) {
    return <SettingsTeams leagueteams={leagueteams} />;
  }

  state = {
    appIsReady: false
  }

  render() {
    console.log("props", this.props.leagueteams.MLS, "EPL", this.props.leagueteams.EPL)
    const { leagueteams } = this.props.leagueteams

    const { listStyle, listBuffer,saveButton, buttonContainer } = styles;

    return (
      <View style={listStyle}>
        <View style={buttonContainer}>
          <Button 
            title="Save Selection"
            color="#FFFFFF"
            onPress= {() => console.log("button pressed")}
            style= {saveButton} />
        </View>

        <View style={listBuffer}>
          <ListView
          dataSource={this.dataSource}
          renderRow={this.renderRow}
          />
        </View>
      </View>

    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { leagueteams: state.leagueteams };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps) (Settings);
```

Comment: If you want to see the individual state, then i would suggest to use the button inside listItem, and if you want all the data, then you could use .map and return another array of what you need, And is it like `this.props.leagueteams.MLS[0].isChecked` ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you probably want to lift the `checked` state of the items up to the Settings component or, since you are using Redux, use the store rather than component state. Managing the `checked` state is done by passing the value into the list item and handling an `onChange` event in the Settings component. Then when your button is pressed in the Settings component you can read the `checked` states from either the Settings's state or the Redux store, whichever you choose. Maintaining the `checked` state inside the individual list item makes it difficult to access from the parent when the button is pressed. See the official documentation on [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) for a more in-depth explanation (web examples, but same principals apply).